# How to post an SWT key event containing just a keyboard character (no modifiers)?

Tags: java, eclipse, events, keyboard, swt

Is it possible to post a `Key` event which contains the character as it should be received by the focused widget?

I want to make a simple pop-up keyboard which generates `Key` events and I would like to make the pop-up keyboard completely independent of the physical keyboard regarding key mapping.

What I currently see is, that when I set the character to '(' without generating shift events, I get an '8' (I have a German keyboard where '(' is Shift+8). I assume that on a different keyboard the '(' will appear as something else again.

Is there any way to by-pass the mapping?

My current code:

```java
private void postKey(Key key) {
    if(shift) {
        Event ke = new Event();
        ke.type = SWT.KeyDown;
        ke.keyCode = SWT.SHIFT;
        refWidget.getDisplay().post(ke);
    }

    Event ke = new Event();
    ke.type = SWT.KeyDown;
    ke.character = shift ? key.shifted[0] : key.normal[0];
    refWidget.getDisplay().post(ke);

    ke.type = SWT.KeyUp;
    refWidget.getDisplay().post(ke);

    if(shift) {
        Event ev = new Event();
        ev.type = SWT.KeyUp;
        ev.keyCode = SWT.SHIFT;
        refWidget.getDisplay().post(ev);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The SWTBot wiki has a page on [keyboard layouts](https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot/Keyboard_Layouts).

If you stick with `Display-post()`, then you need to know the current keyboard layout and map keys to characters (shift + 8 -> '('), like you already observed.
You migh be able to re-use or adopt the relevant classes from SWTBot (`SWTKeyboardStrategy`, `KeyboardLayout`).

As an alternative, the page lists the AWTKeyboardStrategy that uses AWTs `Robot` to simulate key strokes, that might be worth trying.

As a side note: if you had to post a Shift+x key event you would specify the Shift key in the `stateMask` like so:

```
    Event ev = new Event();
    ev.type = SWT.KeyUp;
    ev.stateMask = SWT.SHIFT;
    ev.keyCode = ...
```

Comment: Upon a close look my first answer only applies to `StyledText`. Please see the revised version.

Comment: +1 - thanks for the info. I had hoped that it would be more simple :-) I'll look at the SWTBot pages...